# Assigning Random Items to different sections in R

Tags: r

I have the following summarized values:

```
       section `n_distinct(item_code)`
     <int>                   <int>
1      551                     642
2      552                     609
3      553                     366
4      554                     445
5      555                     274
6      556                    1547
7      557                     227
8      558                     140
9      559                    5519
10     560                       5
11     561                     290
12     562                     147
13     563                     529
14      NA                    9758
```

What I am trying to do is randomly assign each of those 9758 item_codes to one of the 13 sections. Looking to put a condition so that we have equal distribution across the sections, i.e. Section 560 will get more items and Section 559 will get none. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What do you mean 'randomly assign'?  Seems like the items should be assign to 560 first, and then to 560 and 562 after 560 reaches 147 items.  For code, what have you tried? and what result do you want?

Comment: The item_codes are from row 1:9758, these have no Sections assigned to them. I was going to divide these into 11 sections (excluding 556 and 559) and assign them equally across the remaining sections. I was wondering if I could assign them based on conditional, i.e. if Section555 item_code < Section556 item_code, then assign item_code till Section556 and move to the next. Am i making sense?

Comment: So, a assign order vector of length 9758 is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach combining `sample` and `split`:

Define the object to be split.  Consider that `split` requires a factor that defines the grouping of the split. We define that grouping by sampling 1:13 sections 9758 times.  We then use this to split the items.

```
set.seed(1)
item_codes <- 1:9758
split_factor <- sample(1:13, length(item_codes), replace=TRUE)
item_codes_split <- split(item_codes, split_factor)
item_codes_split
```

In this instance you are randomly sampling 1:13, 9758 times, unlikely you will get very uneven groupings (one group has none or very few as you stated) but you will also not get absolutely equal groupings (i.e. 9758/13 ~750-751 in each group).

You can check how many items are in each group by:

```
lengths(item_codes_split)
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13 
787 730 709 765 773 782 735 715 715 724 748 790 785
```

If this distribution works for you then you are set.  Otherwise you have to define a different kind of sampling where you sample 1:9758 for size~750-751 without replacement, remove those sampled items from the list, then sample the remaining again iteratively until you have 13 groups.

Edited: Decided to take this on too, here we have 13 groups of almost equal lengths as described above:

```
set.seed(1)
item_codes_split <- list()
item_codes <- 1:9758

9758/13
# [1] 750.6154 
split_size <- c(rep(c(751, 750), times=6), 9758-751*6-750*6)
split_size
# [1] 751 750 751 750 751 750 751 750 751 750 751 750 752

for (i in 1:13){
  item_codes_split[[i]] <- sample(item_codes, size=split_size[i], replace=FALSE)
  item_codes <- item_codes[-item_codes_split[[i]]]
}
item_codes_split

lengths(item_codes_split)
# [1] 751 750 751 750 751 750 751 750 751 750 751 750 752
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will generate a vector of assign order :

```
df <- data.frame(section = as.character(551:563), items= c(642,609,366,445,274,1547,227,140,5519,5,290,147,529),stringsAsFactors = F)
#       section items
#1      551   642
#2      552   609
#3      553   366
#4      554   445
#5      555   274
#6      556  1547
#7      557   227
#8      558   140
#9      559  5519
#10     560     5
#11     561   290
#12     562   147
#13     563   529
# Your original data,
df <- df[order(df$items),]
steps <- diff(df$items)*seq(nrow(df)-1)
assign_order <- numeric(0)
for(i in seq(nrow(df)-1)){
  assign_order <- c(assign_order, sample(x=df$section[1:i], size =steps[i], replace = T))
} 
# The assign_order have a length of 61007, which means adding 61007 items will make all sections equal (to 5519).
res <-  assign_order[1:9758] # The assign order of your 9758 items.
```

Assign items according to `res` will first fill section 560 to 140 items, and then randomly fill section 560 and section 558 until they both have 147 items, and so on. At last, the items of all sections(except for 556 and 559) will be approximately equal.